# How do I give a JavaFX TextField a Swing-style lowered bevel border?

Tags: java, css, swing, javafx-2

I like the 3D effect of a JTextField with Borders created by BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder(). Now that I'm working with JavaFX instead, the L&F of the border is controlled by CSS. And the default look is just a simple line stroke border. I figured out how to edit the CSS file to thicken the border and change its color:

```
.text-field { -fx-border-color: color; -fx-border-width: #; }
```

But if you look at a Swing-generated lowered bevel effect it is created by having different colors on 2 of the 4 sides and having the edge barrier at a 45 degree angle. So how do I accomplish that with CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) says:

> While the JavaFX CSS parser will parse valid CSS syntax, it is not a
>   fully compliant CSS parser. One should not expect the parser to handle
>   syntax not specified in this document.

`border` or `border-top` and others are ones in this unsupported category.
To have a lowered bevel border try

```
.text-field {
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-width: 2px;
    -fx-border-color: black lightgray lightgray black;
}
```

Or try with JavaFX-style way using inner shadow

```
.text-field {
    -fx-effect: innershadow(three-pass-box, gray, 12 , 0.5, 1, 1);
}
```

However the real style you wanted can be achieved by `-fx-border-style` attribute IMO. Refer to it in over mentioned guide.

Comment: Thanks, but could you give me a simplified breakdown on the ref guide's explanation of the fx-border-style attribute? This doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me: 

<border-style> [ , <border-style> ]* where <border-style> = <dash-style> [phase <number>]? [centered | inside | outside]? [line-join [miter <number> | bevel | round]]? [line-cap [square | butt | round]]? where <dash-style> = [ none | solid | dotted | dashed | segments( <number>, <number> [, <number>]*) ]

Comment: Btw, using the 4 different fx-border-colors did work fairly well. It isn't perfect since the edges aren't angled, but I imagine I'd have to use the line join settings in border-style to achieve that.

Comment: OK I think I got it. The CSS I used:
.text-field {
    -fx-background-color: #BEBEBE;
    -fx-border-color: #676767 white white #676767;
    -fx-border-style: solid inside line-join miter;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
-fx-border-color: top right bottom left;
-fx-border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
```

Comment: This only creates lines which meet at right angles rather than the 45 degree mitre that the person wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the Swing style you are refering to, but from your description this should give you a beveled look.

You should be able to do it by simply defining the border as **inset** rather than the default of *solid*.

```
.text-field {
    border: 4px inset #aaaaaa;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want more control you can set each side of the border a different color:

```
.text-field {
    border-top: 4px solid #555555;
    border-left: 4px solid #555555;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-right: 4px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

[​There are also *outset*, *ridge* and other border types to play around with.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Comment: style="border: 4px inset #aaaaaa;" on a tab pane produces an invisible border